# Create a new column that is populated by the previous row of a different column in R

Tags: r

My data are as follows:

```
site setup.date  revisit.date end.date
A    2019-07-15  2019-07-22   2019-07-22
A    2019-07-15  2019-07-29   2019-07-29
A    2019-07-15  2019-08-04   2019-08-01
A    2019-07-15  2019-08-18   2019-08-18
B    2019-07-22  2019-07-23   2019-07-23
B    2019-07-22  2019-07-30   2019-07-25
B    2019-07-22  2019-08-05   2019-08-05
B    2019-07-22  2019-08-19   2019-08-19
```

I would like to create a new column, "begin.date" that is populated by the previous row in "revisit.date" for each "site". If it is the first row in the "site", assign "begin.date" as "setup.date" for that "site". The first two rows of my desired output would be as follows:

```
site setup.date  revisit.date begin.date  end.date    
A    2019-07-15  2019-07-22   2019-07-15  2019-07-22   
A    2019-07-15  2019-07-29   2019-07-22  2019-07-29
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(begin.date = lag(revisit.date, default = first(setup.date)), .after = revisit.date)  #Thanks to @onyambu

  site  setup.date revisit.date begin.date end.date  
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>        <chr>      <chr>     
1 A     2019-07-15 2019-07-22   2019-07-15 2019-07-22
2 A     2019-07-15 2019-07-29   2019-07-22 2019-07-29
3 A     2019-07-15 2019-08-04   2019-07-29 2019-08-01
4 A     2019-07-15 2019-08-18   2019-08-04 2019-08-18
5 B     2019-07-22 2019-07-23   2019-07-22 2019-07-23
6 B     2019-07-22 2019-07-30   2019-07-23 2019-07-25
7 B     2019-07-22 2019-08-05   2019-07-30 2019-08-05
8 B     2019-07-22 2019-08-19   2019-08-05 2019-08-19
```

Comment: This is a good answer, though there is `.after` in `mutate` and `lag` does have a `default` parameterJust use `lag(revisit.date, default=...), .after=...`

Comment: @onyambu Thanks for a great tip! I didn't know that I can set location in `mutate` part :).

Comment: Now you know. What about the `lag`? why not set `lag(revisit.date, default = setup.date[1])`? why use `replace_na`?

Comment: Now you know. What about the lag? why not set lag(revisit.date, default = setup.date[1])? why use replace_na

Comment: @onyambu I should look more carefully about arguments that I can use. Thanks again :D

Comment: Yeah. sometimes there are `NA` in the lagged variable that need to be maintained yet still want a particular value in the start of the lagged variable, that is why its not advicable to use `replace_na`